# Recomplie a swf file of a flash project that come without as3proj file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, compiler-errors

I have a folder of flash source code and what I would like to do is modify a action script file and recompile the swf again.

Unfortuneatly , I found that the source code do not have as3proj file . What I have is like this

FlashProject:

- org/as2lib
- project.fla
- as files

And I tried to create a new project and what I saw is rsc, bin and lib folder, Then I tried to put the file like this:

- lib/org/as2lib
- rsc/as files
- project.fla

What it generate is a white swf without any content, what should i do to compile it ? I am using flashDevelop ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new project, dismantle your FLA in Adobe Flash (trial will do) via exporting an SWF, then you grab resources out of that SWF within FlashDevelop, and use them accordingly. Migrating from Adobe Flash into FD is no simple task.

That FLA you have is an Adobe Flash project file, which FlashDevelop cannot read. So you have to start a new project, and embed your existing assets in FlashDevelop's way.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I need to get flash cs6 to  recompile the swf file? That is the only way?

Comment: Out of a FLA, yes, as any assets you make are hidden in there. But, you can use an earlier version of Adobe Flash CS, also you don't have to buy it right away, just install as trial, compile the SWF, then go to FlashDevelop - you'll see it having a lot of resources you can then use.

Comment: I see . But I can see the action script file i want right now and I have edited it, all I need to finish the job is compile the new swf file. I would use cs6 to try then, Is it possible to do without the as3proj file?

Comment: Sure, the FLA file you have there is the project file for Adobe Flash.

Comment: Thanks. Let me get a demo and try first